# RPC Failed when parsing PDF documents using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, rpc

I have a small VBA script that reads values of objects in PDF documents and populates Microsoft access database. The script runs fine for a bit and after it has scanned a few files, it returns an error:

> Run-time error '-2147023170 (800706be)'
>
> Automation error
>
> The remote procedure call failed.

Before it would do about 20 files, so I had to scan 20 files at a time, but now that I have increased the number or records written to database per PDF file, it barely finishes one file.

I am  using:

> Windows 7 Enterprise
>
> SP1 Microsoft Excel 2010

Further, these are the references I am using in Excel:

> Visual Basic for Applications
>
> Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object library
>
> Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object library
>
> Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type library
>
> Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
>
> Microsoft Office 15.0 Object library

And finally here is my code:

```
Private Sub browseButton_Click()

 Dim fdl As FileDialog
 Dim FilePath, FileName As String
 Dim FileNum As Integer

 filesListBox.Clear

 Set fdl = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

'Set the caption of the dialog box,
 fdl.Title = "Please Select a PDF File"
 'Set the InitialFile Path
 fdl.InitialFileName = "c:\"
 'Set the Folder View
 fdl.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewSmallIcons
 'Set the filter
 fdl.Filters.Clear
 fdl.Filters.Add "Excel Macros Files", "*.pdf"

 fdl.Show
 FileNum = 1
 For Each file In fdl.SelectedItems()
   FilePath = fdl.SelectedItems(FileNum)
   filesListBox.AddItem (FilePath)
   FileNum = FileNum + 1
 Next

 fNum.Text = filesListBox.ListCount
End Sub

Private Sub examineButton_Click()
    Dim AcroApp As Acrobat.CAcroApp
    Dim theForm As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rh, rc As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim jso, check As Object
    Dim fIndex, i, j, k, rKey As Integer
    Dim pre, hazard, control, work, task, tdate, employee As String
    Dim score() As Variant

    score = Range("B3:BU64").value

    For Each file In filesListBox.List

        Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\bokhanca\Desktop\Current Projects\Datamine Project\FLHA Database\FLHADB_2.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    cn.Open

    If filesListBox.ListCount = 0 Then
         MsgBox ("No files selected")
         Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    Set theForm = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

        If IsNull(file) Then
            Exit For
        End If

        Set rf = New ADODB.Recordset
        Set rg = New ADODB.Recordset


        With rf
            .Open "FLHA", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic, adCmdTable
        End With
        With rg
            .Open "GeneralTable", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic, adCmdTable
        End With


        fIndex = fIndex + 1
        theForm.Open (file)
        Set jso = theForm.GetJSObject

        work = jso.getField("work").value
        tdate = jso.getField("date").value
        employee = jso.getField("Tech 1").value

        rf.AddNew
        rf("Employee").value = employee
        rf("Work").value = work
        rf("Task_Date").value = tdate

        rKey = rf("ID").value

        For i = 0 To 8
            If i = 0 Then
                pre = ""
            Else
                pre = i
            End If

            task = jso.getField("Task " & (i + 1)).value

            If task <> "" Then

             For j = 1 To 62
                hazard = jso.getField(pre & "Hazard" & j).value

                For k = 1 To 71
                    control = jso.getField(pre & "Control" & k).value

                    If hazard <> "Off" And control <> "Off" And score(j, k) <> 0 Then
                        rg.AddNew
                        rg("ID").value = rKey
                        rg("Employee").value = employee
                        rg("Work").value = work
                        rg("Task").value = task
                        rg("Hazard").value = hazard
                        rg("Control").value = control
                        rg("Task_Date").value = tdate
                    End If
                Next

             Next

            End If
        Next
        theForm.Close
        fNum.Text = filesListBox.ListCount - fIndex

        rf.Update
        rg.Update

        rf.Close
        rg.Close

        Set rf = Nothing
        Set rg = Nothing

         cn.Close

    Set cn = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    AcroApp.Exit
    Set AcroApp = Nothing
    Set theForm = Nothing

    Next

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub}
```

Comment: Side note: when you `Dim a, b, c As SomeType` only `c` is declared as `SomeType`, the others are `Variant`. (May or may not be related to your issue)

Comment: Thanks for the note. I changed the decleration of the "jso as object" to be by itself since the debugger says the fault occurs when trying to jso.getField from PDF doc, but made not difference.